# How to speed-up the data fetching process from multiple XMLs across folders

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest how to speed up the fetching process for required data from only selective folders.

Present coding is checking all 'tx1.xml's for fetching, where some thousands of tx1.xml are present. We required to fetch from 'JOURNALs' which are mentioned in 'Journals.txt' file.

**Folder structure:**

```
D:\Rudramuni\XSLTPrograms\FilesFetch\Files\AJN\3456\Over\tx1.xml
D:\Rudramuni\XSLTPrograms\FilesFetch\Files\AJN\3457\Over\tx1.xml
D:\Rudramuni\XSLTPrograms\FilesFetch\Files\EB\7654\Over\tx1.xml
D:\Rudramuni\XSLTPrograms\FilesFetch\Files\CLS\1234\Over\tx1.xml <!--Not required because not mentioned in 'Journal.txt'-->
```

**Path.txt**

```
<path>
<a>D:\Rudramuni\XSLTPrograms\FilesFetch\Files</a>
</path>
```

**Journals.txt**

```
<root>
AJN
EB
</root>
```

**Input XML (..\AJN\3457\Over\tx1.xml):**

```
<article>
<fm>
    <title>Article One</title>
    <aug><au><fnm>Rudramuni</fnm><snm>TP</snm></au></aug>
</fm>
 </article>
```

In above files, scripts are needs to find only three 'tx1.xml's because in 'Journal.txt' **AJN** and **EB** only mentioned.

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:variable name="varFile" select="document('Path.txt')"/><!--Path of files which given in Path.txt-->
<xsl:variable name="varPath" select="translate($varFile/path/a, '\', '/')"/>

<xsl:variable name="varFile1" select="document('Journals.txt')"/><!--Text file is having Journals name for fetching information-->
<xsl:variable name="varJs"><!--each line of txt file will get tag 'a' -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$varFile1/root/text()">
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\n')[normalize-space()]">
            <a><xsl:sequence select="normalize-space()"/></a>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="str1" select="concat('file:///', $varPath,'/?select=tx1.xml;recurse=yes;on-error=ignore')"/>

<xsl:variable name="varFinal">
    <xsl:for-each select="$varJs/a">
        <xsl:variable name="varJName" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="varCollection">
            <xsl:copy-of select="collection($str1)
                [matches(document-uri(.), $varJName) and matches(document-uri(.), '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/Over/tx1.xml')]"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <fnm><xsl:value-of select="$varCollection//*:fnm"/></fnm><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:value-of select="$varFinal"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required output**

```
Rudramuni Kishan
Likhith
```

**XSLT processor:**
Saxon9he

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your stylesheet, you seem to be loading all `tx1.xml` files under `D:\Rudramuni\XSLTPrograms\FilesFetch\Files`, but what you want is only those files that are relative to this path, but mentioned in "journals.txt".

Instead of creating a variable globally to be loaded by the `collection` function, change it into a loop or use apply-templates on the parsed variable of "journals.txt", i.e. `$varJs`. You have already started doing this in your `$varFinal`.

Change this:

> ```
> <xsl:copy-of select="collection($str1)
>      [matches(document-uri(.), $varJName) 
>      and matches(document-uri(.), '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/Over/tx1.xml')]"/>
> ```

to this:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="collection(f:get-path($varPath, .))" />
```

Add the following global variable (and remove `$str1`):

```
<xsl:variable name="collection-query" 
    select="'?select=tx1.xml;recurse=yes;on-error=ignore'"/>
```

Add the following function:

```
<xsl:function name="f:get-path" as="xs:string">
    <xsl:param name="base" as="xs:string" />
    <xsl:param name="segment" as="xs:string" />
    <xsl:sequence select="concat('file:///', $base, '/', $segment, '/', $collection-query)" />
</xsl:function>
```

Remove the following line:

> ```
> <xsl:variable name="varJName" select="."/>
> ```

Note, I didn't test this, as it would require me to set up a whole directory structure, but something along these lines will work. Plus having the creation of the URI in a function makes it easier to fix it closer to your requirements.

Since you already have a pre-selection on the `tx1.xml` in the collection uri, and you now have a selection based only on the files you actually need from "journals.txt", there seems to be no need for the predicate in your original code in the `xsl:copy-of` statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion sir, now scripts are working fine, plus one.